# Generate BTC wallets React + Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, supabase

Is there a JavaScript library compatible with Vite and React that can generate BTC wallets similar to ethers.js for Ethereum? If not, how can I generate BTC wallets on the server side using Supabase and render the results in my React component?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.